# ORA-00904 invalid identifier on generated query from linq

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

I have this linq :-

```
var query = from r in Ctx.Reg
            select new
            {
                IdReg = r.Id,
                ...
                Status1 = r.Hist.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).Take(1).Any(x=> x.Status == 2),
                Status2 = r.Hist.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).Skip(1).Take(1).Any(x=> x.Status == 5)
            };
```

The generated query contains:

```
WHERE ("Extent1"."REP_ID" = "Extent2"."REP_ID")
```

I'm getting the message

> ORA-00904: "Extent1"."REP_ID".

Both columns exists and have the same datatype.
What can I do for this issue ?

Comment: Not clear without the all oracle query (even if it's big). By the way, why don't u use `r.Hist.Any()` and `r.Hist.Count() > 1` instead of your take / skip /any for status1 and status2 ?

Comment: I have a clause that I forgot to write in the Any() sentence, like this: Any(x => x.Status == 2);

Comment: @LennonFerreira Maybe you could return the `Hist` items in the query then do that logic in Linq-to-Objects instead.

Comment: I can't because the query result returns data for a pagination grid, and this two status that I'm getting from Hist may influence that data, I need to do all logic before executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but it works:

```
var query = from r in Ctx.Reg
            select new
            {
                IdReg = r.Id,
                ...
                Status1 = Ctx.RegHist.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).Any(x=> x.RegId == r.Id && x.Status == 2),
                Status2 = Ctx.RegHist.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).Skip(1).Any(x=> x.RegId == r.Id && x.Status == 5)
            };
```